# URLRequest blocks UI until request completed

Tags: ios, swift

So, I know there's a lot of documentation about it, but I still can't wrap my head around this issue.
I have a Search Bar that performs a search while typing and updates a Table View. Thing is, until the request is completed, my app is completely frozen. I tried putting the task in the background queue, but it still freezes.
How would you perform the fetch. JSON decoding and image retrieval while maintaining the app fluid? The moment the text in my search bar changes I can discard whatever request is processing because it's not relevant anymore.
The code in my View that performs the search is the following:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [self] in
            store.searchMovies(query: searchText) { (moviesResult) in
                switch moviesResult {
                case let .success(movies):
                    MovieResults.movieResults.allResults.removeAll()
                    for movie in movies {
                        MovieResults.movieResults.allResults.append(movie)
                        if let posterPath = movie.poster_path {
                            let url = URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/\(posterPath)")!
                            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) { movie.thumb = data }
                            else { movie.thumb = self.genericPosterImageData }
                        }
                        movie.isAddedToList = false
                        //print("Name: \(movie.title), Poster URL: \(movie.poster_path!), Released: \(movie.releaseDate!)")
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case let .failure(error):
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
        }

    }
```

while the functions that performs the search are the following:

```
func searchMovies(query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Movie], Error>) -> Void){
        let url = TMDB_API.movieSearchURL(query: query)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data,response,error) in
            let result = self.processMoviesRequest(data: data, error: error)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }

    private func processMoviesRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Result<[Movie], Error> {
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            return .failure(error!)
        }
        return TMDB_API.movies(fromJSON: jsonData)
    }
    
    func processImageRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Result<UIImage, Error> {
        guard
            let imageData = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
            // Couldn't create an image
            if data == nil {
                return .failure(error!)
            } else {
                return .failure(MovieError.imageCreationError)
            }
        }
        return .success(image)
    }

    static func movies(fromJSON data: Data) -> Result<[Movie], Error> {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
            let tmdbResponseQuery = try decoder.decode(tmdbResponse.self, from: data)
            let movies = tmdbResponseQuery.movies.filter { $0.poster_path != nil && $0.releaseDate != nil}
            return .success(movies)
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)` Why do you need to download the image right away? That's a long blocking task... Why not use something like SDWebImage, KingFisher, Alamofire+Image ? And `self.tableView.reloadData()` should be called on main thread. You are also doing the parsing of the response in Main Thread? And you create each time a `DateFormatter`, why not keep a `JSONDecoder()` as a static var and use it to decode? Or at least the dateformatter?

Answer (score 0):

perform UI updates on main thread

put DispatchQueue.main.async {} after success case